# Grails criteria query fails with synatx error when using MYSQL

Tags: grails

I have a query that fails when the application is connected to a MYSQL instance.  The query works fine when using the H2 memory database.  All other queries work fine with MYSQL.

error Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Controller Action:

```
def index() {
def currentUser = currentUser()
def peopleFollowing = currentUser.following
def c = Post.createCriteria()
    def postList = c.list  {
       'in' ("user", peopleFollowing)
       'order' "dateCreated", "desc"
    }
[postList:postList, user : currentUser, peopleFollowing:peopleFollowing]
}
```

The query runs against the MYSQL when I remove the in clause.  So it seems that the:  'in' ("user", peopleFollowing) is causing the issue.  I think problem is that in is a MYSQL reserved word.  I've tried using backticks around in, but keep getting syntax errors...?

```
class Post {


String content
Date dateCreated
User user


static belongsTo = [user : User]

static hasMany = [postComments: PostComment]

static constraints = {
    content (blank: false)
}

static mapping = {
    sort dateCreated:"desc"
    content type:"text"
    postComments sort:"dateCreated",  order:"desc"
}
```

}

class Post {
    String content
    Date dateCreated
    User user
    static belongsTo = [user : User]
    static hasMany = [postComments: PostComment]
    static constraints = {
        content (blank: false)
    }
    static mapping = {
        sort dateCreated:"desc"
        content type:"text"
        postComments sort:"dateCreated",  order:"desc"
    }
}
    class Post {
    String content
    Date dateCreated
    User user
    static belongsTo = [user : User]
    static hasMany = [postComments: PostComment]
    static constraints = {
        content (blank: false)
    }
    static mapping = {
        sort dateCreated:"desc"
        content type:"text"
        postComments sort:"dateCreated",  order:"desc"
    }
    }

Comment: I would look at the generated SQL and go from there.  For what it's worth, `in` is actually a groovy reserved word and must be in quotes; `order` is not reserved and doesn't need the quotations - `order("dateCreated", "desc")`

Comment: could you please add your relevant domains to post

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I seem to remember we had to rename our 'User' entity to 'OurAppNameUser' for this precise reason...

Comment: Thanks for the ideas everyone..I was able to determine that the order clause does work by itself.  The thought that the word 'user' might be causing the problem is definitely valid, although I have used it in other criteria queries in my application.  I'm using MySQL 5.6.27 with Grails 2.0.3  Maybe I just need a different version?  I'm going to look at the generated sql..  I sure hope I don't have to rename my user class.  Any more thoughts would be great. I'll edit my post to include relevant domains..

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by doing this instead:

```
def postList = Post.findAllByUserInList( peopleFollowing )
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the `id`s and adding one `0` to the `List`:

```
def currentUser = currentUser()
def peopleFollowingIds = currentUser.following.id
peopleFollowingIds.add(0)
def c = Post.createCriteria()
def postList = c.list  {
    'in' ("user_id", peopleFollowingIds)
    'order' "dateCreated", "desc"
}
```

Or something like that.